# Show that the two conditions are equivalent $f(x+1)=f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a real-valued class $C^1$ function on $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfy $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. At this time show that the following two conditions are equivalent.

1. Improper integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1+f(x)^2}} dx$ converges
2. There is no $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$

I translated from a different language by google translator but I think this translation is correct but I do not have any idea to proceed with the problem. Any hint or answer would be appreciated.

Comment: If (2) holds, maybe you can take $a>0$ the lower bound of $|f(x)|$ and bound the value of the integral there

Comment: To amplify the hint from @Bimo Adityarahman, use continuity of $f$ to get a positive lower bound on the interval $[1,2]$ and then use $f(x)=f(x+1)$ to show it's a lower bound everywhere. The converse implication, from 1 to 2, looks more delicate and will really need the assumption that $f$ is not just continuous but $C^1$.

Comment: For (2) to (1), I think you may manipulate the expression to be the infinite sum of $\Sigma_n \int \frac{1}{(n+p)^{1+f(p)^2}} dp$, then switch the sum and the integral, bound and calculate the inner sum using integral, then argue the convergence from $\frac{1}{f(p)^2}$.

Comment: @BimoAdityarahman How did you transform the integral with an infinite sum, why did you change the integrand with $n, p$ could you please write an answer

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear, I partitioned the integral into infinite sum of integrals with bounds from $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, to infinity. So we have $n$ the integral part going from $1, 2$ to infinity and $p$ the remainder going from $0$ to $1$ ($x=n+p$), as $f(x)=f(n+p)=f(p)$ for $n$ integer anyway.

Comment: It is an unnecessary and complicated way anyway, if you already know there exist $a > 0$, the lower bound of $|f(x)|$ (which must exist because otherwise by the continuity of $f$, you can find the zeros of $f$ by taking a limit), then you have the integral less than the integral of $\frac{1}{x^{1+a^2}}$ where $1+a^2 > 1$ which makes it converges.

Comment: @BimoAdityarahman Thank you very much. to show the two conditions are equivalent, is it necessary to show that (1) follows (2) and (2) follows (1)?

Comment: Yes, that is only for the (2) => (1), for (1) => (2) I think is solved by Sungjin Kim

Answer (score 2):

(2)=>(1) is solved in comments.

For (1)=>(2), we proceed as follows.

Suppose that (2) is false. There is $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(c)=0$, and take $c\in [2,3]$. We have $f(c+n)=0$ for any integer $n$ by $f(x+1)=f(x)$.

If $x\geq 2$, we see that
$$
\frac1{x^{f(x)^2}}\geq \frac13 \Longleftrightarrow |f(x)|\leq \sqrt{\frac{\log 3}{\log x}}.
$$

Since $f\in C^1$, we have $f'(x+1)=f'(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f'$ is bounded. Let $M>0$ and $|f'(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, we have Lipschitz continuity of $f$, that is,
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y| \ \mathrm{for \ any} \ x, y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Hence, for any integer $n\geq 2$, we have
$$
|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(c+n)|\leq  \sqrt{\frac{\log 2}{\log n}}$$
for any $$
x \in I_n:=\left( c+n - \frac1M\sqrt{\frac{\log 2}{\log n}}, c+n + \frac1M\sqrt{\frac{\log 2}{\log n}}\right).
$$
This sequence of intervals $I_n$ becomes eventually disjoint for sufficiently large $n$, say $n\geq n_0$.
Now, the integral in (1) satisfies
$$
\int_1^{\infty} \frac1{x^{1+f(x)^2}} dx\geq \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} \int_{I_n}\frac1{x^{1+f(x)^2}} dx \geq \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}\int_{I_n}\frac1{3x} dx.
$$

For each $n\geq n_0$,
$$
\int_{I_n} \frac1x dx = \log\left( \frac{c+n + \frac1M\sqrt{\frac{\log 2}{\log n}}}{c+n - \frac1M\sqrt{\frac{\log 2}{\log n}}}\right)\asymp \frac1{n\sqrt{\log n}}.
$$
Since $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}\frac1{n\sqrt{\log n}}=\infty$, we have the divergence of $\int_1^{\infty} \frac1{x^{1+f(x)^2}} dx$. Therefore, (1) is false.

Comment: You are proved (2) to (1) right?

Comment: I proved (2) is false -> (1) is false. So, equivalently (1) -> (2).

Comment: Thanks, In line two "We have $f(c+n)=0$ for any integer $n$ by $f(x+1)=f(x)$" could you expain bit

Comment: If $x\geq 2$, then $\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{2} \implies \frac{1}{x^{f(x)^2}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$ so how do you get $\frac{1}{x^{f(x)^2}} \geq \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: 1. By $f(x)=f(x+1)=f(x+2)=\cdots$, we have $f(c+n)=0$ for integers $n$. 
2. What I wrote there is the equivalence below. 
$$\frac1{x^{f(x)^2}}\geq \frac13 \Longleftrightarrow |f(x)|\leq \sqrt{\frac{\log 3}{\log x}}.$$
Just solve for $f(x)$ in the above.

Comment: 2. yes that is true I understand but is there a reason to take that inequality $\frac{1}{x^{f(x)^2}} \geq \frac{1}{3}$.  Where it comes from?

Comment: We need it where we lower estimate the integral by $\int 1/(3x) dx$.

Comment: But as in my comment, the inequality is wrong. Right?

Comment: 3. Hence for any integer $n\geq 2$, we have .."the inequality".. how do you get it?

Comment: $|f(x)|= |f(x)-f(c+n)| \leq \sqrt{\frac{\log 3}{\log x}}$ is OK. How do we participate $\sqrt{\frac{\log 2}{\log n}}$ for this ?

Comment: $\log 2<\log 3$ so $|f(x)|\leq \sqrt{\frac{\log 3}{\log x}}$ is true. Then eventually $\frac1{x^{f(x)^2}}\geq \frac13$ is true.

Comment: why $f^\prime$ is bounded?

Comment: Class $C^1$ and periodic, so $f'$ is continuous periodic.